# Secure pairing support in various RF standards

Tags: iot

I would like to understand if secure pairing can be implemented in all (or none)? IoT RF standards.

For example: BLE provides Out-of-band possibility, which seems like only really secure option to me. But I have hard time finding information on security of WiFi/Z wave/ZigBee/XBee/LoRa/Ingenu/TI15.4 and other protocolls during pairing.

Could you suggest some standards which support secure pairing "out-of-the-box"?